# Parse txt file and save in python variable

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a txt file containing following lines

```
term accept_1  
protocol:: tcp 
destination-port:: 24  


term accept_2  
protocol:: tcp 
source-port:: 21  
source-port-port:: 22
```

What I am trying to do is the following:
**for each term**, save the protocol in one variable, and the ports too (probably in an array).

I end up my research with PLY (Python Lex-Yacc), but I found it overcomplicated for my needs.

My actual code:

```py
with fileinput.FileInput(file_pol,inplace = True, backup ='.bak') as policy:
        for line in policy:
            if "destination-port::" in line:
                extract_port = re.findall("\d+",line)
            elif  "source-port::" in line:
                extract_port = re.findall("\d+",line)
```

The above is basically working but I miss the relation between term, protocol, port.

Comment: You should store it in a dictionary, with the `term` as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
from collections import defaultdict

policy_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for line in policy:
    key, value = line.strip().split()
    if key == 'term':
        term = value
    elif key.endswith('::')
        policy_dict[term][key[:-2]] = value
```